# Custom Field box history

Tags: custom-field

I entered a test value ("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh") in my custom field box at some point, and now it always appears in the drop down when I am trying to select a value. Is there some way to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a search for this phrase: "wordpress remove custom field value from the drop down menu". A bit verbose perhaps, but it got me this link: http://sumtips.com/2011/03/add-delete-edit-custom-fields-wordpress.html

From that page, the author states that you can do one of the following:

- Delete Custom Field from all posts.
- Delete it from the database.
- Delete it using a plugin.

There's a lot more detail in the link above, but to not steal their thunder, I'll let you following the link itself.